# Index of a random item from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following list:

```
cnames = [" green ", " blue ", " yellow ", " gray ", " pink ", " orange ", "purple ", " red ", "brown "]
```

How do I get 6 random and unique indexes representing a number between `0`    and 
    `len(cnames)`     from that list?

Comment: Just for clarity, what do you mean by 6 random and unique indexes? Do you mean 6 unique integers representing a number between `0` and `len(cnames)` or 6 unique strings matching strings in the list?

Comment: @GarretGutierrez I mean 6 unique integers representing a number between 0 and len(cnames)

Comment: `random.sample(range(len(cnames),k=6)` will sample without replacement 6 numbers between 0 and len(cnames). U can use `choices(...)` if you want them with replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The **random** module should help.

```
import random
random.sample(cnames, 6)   #random.sample returns unique list of random choice. 

random.sample(range(len(cnames)), 6)#to get random int representing a number between 0 and len(cnames)
```

**Output:**

```
[' gray ', ' pink ', 'purple ', ' blue ', ' orange ', ' green ']
```

Comment: he wanted integers , so sample of (len(cnames),6) would be closer