# Random and unique indexes from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following list:

```
cnames = [" green ", " blue ", " yellow ", " gray ", " pink ", " orange ", "purple ", " red ", "brown "]
```

How do I get 6 random and unique indexes representing a number between `0` and  `len(cnames)` from that list?

Comment: can you use numpy or any other library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index of a random item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236418/index-of-a-random-item-from-a-list)

Comment: Not only is this an exact duplicate, it was asked by the same user 2 hours ago, and marked a duplicate then as well.  @dasranke please refrain from asking the same duplicate questions multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to randomly select an item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list); @Rakesh's link is already marked as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python standard library `random` and its function [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random

print(random.sample(range(len(cnames)), 6))
```

Comment: Answer is great, but please do not leave code only answers, maybe a very brief explanation of what sample does in general.

Comment: Updated the post with the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.shuffle(list)` method, and `pop()` method on the list. Here is an example:

```
>>> cnames = ["red", "green", "blue", "grey", "orange"]
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(cnames)
>>> cnames.pop()
'green'
>>> cnames.pop()
'grey'
>>> cnames.pop()
'red'
>>> cnames
['blue', 'orange']
>>>
```